# How to insert UTF8 character with a PHP form and MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want replace in a column UTF8 characters with others UTF8 characters, using a PHP form and REGEXP_REPLACE in MySQL/MariaDB.

```
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($id_mysql, $_POST['search']);
$new = mysqli_real_escape_string($id_mysql, $_POST['new']);
mysqli_query ($id_mysql,
    "UPDATE table_name
    SET column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '$search', '$new')
    WHERE column_name REGEXP '$search'"
    ) or die(mysqli_error($id_mysql));
```

Edit :

To better understand the problem, I have strip mysqli_real_escape_string.

Sorry, \x{26A1} works in the search with PHP REGEX, not MySQL REGEX. MySQL use \u{26A1}.

(Forget the hexadecimal code, it's an example.)

With :

```
$search = "\u{264B}";
$new = "\u{264C}";
```

It works.

BUT: if i sent \u{264B} or "\u{264B}" in the search with the **form**, it does not work.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$new = "\u{264C}";
```

It seems that with the form and the $_POST, \u{264B} becomes a string.

I know double quotes are important. PHP needs double quotes for understand it’s a unicode character. With single quotes, PHP understand it’s a string. I think it’s the key of the problem. But i don’t know how use double quotes with the $_POST. I tried differents ways with no success.

And it’s a simple example. I want use more complex searchs and replacements.

@stackoverflow your related question has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: 1. Check your MYSQL character encoding on the tables
2. Use a modern PHP framework or at least the PDO extension which supports placeholders. `mysql_*` functions are very old and very insecure. Your code has a SQL Injection vulnerability due to passing unsanitized user input to the query

Comment: @Cfreak the code in the question uses mysqli, not mysql

Comment: Why not pass the UTF8 character instead of the hex string?

Comment: If i pass directly the UTF8 character, it works. But if i only know the hex string, how do i do ? I want to use the hex string. \x{26A1} works in the search, I’m sure there must be a way to use it in the replacement.

Comment: `0x2681` is not a valid utf8 character. Utf8 characters starting from 0x00 to 0x7F are one byte characters (ASCII). I assume it is a unicode point, which would be 0xE29AA1 in utf8 (high voltage).

Comment: @Georg it’s 26A1, not 2681.

Comment: Was a typo, but doesn't  make a difference - 0x26 is in the range 0x00 - 0x7F: `select cast(0x26A1 as char charset utf8mb4);show warnings;` ->  `Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '\xA1'`

Comment: Un-duplicating; this is not a character set problem and this Question cannot be resolved with mysqli.

Comment: @GeorgRichter - 0x26A1 is not the same as \u26A1. The former is two unlikely characters (&¡); the latter is a single Unicode codepoint for "high voltage sign": ♁.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way and the only way is to copy/past the UTF8 character directly in the form.

Thanks slaakso and Rick James.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the hex string to unicode character in PHP:

```
mb_convert_encoding('&#'.hexdec($_POST['new']), 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Or you can use PHP's Unicode character escaping (assuming you are trying to insert the high voltage character:

```
$_POST['new'] = "\u{26A1}";
```

Comment: Thank you, but your answer does not satisfy me. I want to send more complex requests, whether in search or replacement, which I retrieve in POST. I can't use PHP functions. I want to use the hexadecimal code directly in the replacement, a bit like \x{26A1} (which works in the search).

Comment: @Arnaud Or use unicode character escaping

Answer (score 0):

We need to know more about the dataflow.

Assuming the HTML is expecting UTF-8:

- The end-user should paste the actual character into the `<form> <input>`.
- No conversion should be done in PHP
- The target column in MySQL should be declared to be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  The `COLLATION` does not matter (at least for this discussion).
- Properly escape or bind the character as it is fed to an `INSERT` statement.

For example, entering `⚡` should show `E29AA1` when doing `SELECT HEX(col)...` to see the hex for the character in the table.

If you want to be "nice" to the user, you could allow them to enter `0xE29AA1` or `U+26A1`.  The former is the UTF-8 (utf8mb4) hex with `0x` as a common indicator of such.  The latter is the common way to spell the Unicode "codepoint" for that same character.  The Ox and U+ would require your PHP code to discover such, convert it to the character, etc.

In some contexts, `\u{26A1}` will be automatically converted to that single character.

HTML "entities" -- `&#x26A1;` will show as the character as the page is being rendered.  Yes, you could store those 8 characters in the database, with the assumption that the only use for the text is to render it via HTML.

`&#9889;` is the decimal equivalent of `&#x26A1;` -- either works equally well *on HTML pages*.

See also https://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E2%9A%A1

Note:  `%E2%9A%A1` is the "URL encoding" for the character.

Comment: The end-user is me. The target column is UTF8_general_ci. But this is not the problem, because it works with $search = "\u{264B}"; $new = "\u{264C}";. I tried to convert the string, but i have 2 problems. The first: I have an error when i want use \u in the search. \u is forbidden by PCRE (like \L, \U…). The second: I can’t insert a UTF8 character with a Back reference. "\u{26A1}" works, but "\u{'${1}'}" don’t work. I tried so many ways. I dont want use HTML entities. So, the best way and only way is to copy/past the UTF8 character directly in the form.

Comment: @Arnaud - If possible, everone (user, database, api, etc) should be storing/using the actual characters, not encodings (`\x`, `\u`, `/`, &, %, etc) _except_ when handing off to the the next process.  And be sure that the recipient is willing to un-encode _that_ encoding automatically.  (Yes, it is challenging to know which encoding to use when.)

Comment: « storing/using the actual characters ». It’s exactly what i want ! With $search = "\u{264B}"; $new = "\u{264C}"; this insert the actual character. But when i use the form, the form convert "\u{264C}" in a string ! I think it’s the key of the problem. It doesn’t matter, the best way and only way is to copy/past the UTF8 character directly in the form.